# XSD for Decoding in Logic Apps an X12 830 02000

Tags: biztalk, azure-logic-apps, edi, x12

I am looking for the XSD to use to support a Decoding action in Logic Apps for the X12 830 00200. This was approved by ANSI in 1986 (pre-ASC), but is still widely used by Ford. I understand the same XSD would be used in a BizTalk Server solution. Does anyone have one to share?

I have tried the download item MicrosoftEdiXSDTemplates.zip as part of Microsoft Azure BizTalk Services SDK Setup:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39087

However that only goes back to 00204, which I tried unsuccessfully adapting.

I would rather not do this as a Flat File Decode, as I want all X12 830 processing in my Logic Apps solution to have a consistent, Agreement-based configuration.

I have sample EDI, drawn from the real-world.

I will be using Ford's specs for the v002001FORD 830O to validate any schema I obtain or create: https://www.gsec.ford.com/GEC/edispecs/830.pdf

** UPDATE **

Thanks all for the help. It ends up that on the MS side, the Kusto log analytics trace of my run-time activity shows explicit duplicate schema references in my Agreement, while my run-time exception from Logic Apps does not clearly indicate a duplicate schema issue is present: 'The message has an unknown document type and did not resolve to any of the existing schemas configured in the agreement.' So, there was nothing wrong with my schema. I just had to tweak my Agreement configuration. I am reporting this to MS and hope the schema validation in the Agreement and/or the exception reporting will be improved.

To me a broader issue is that the X12 schema provided are ASC-issued ones: 02000, 03000, 04000, etc.. The same ones prevented from being shared on Git due to copyright issues. The reason I believe I am running into older, ANSI-issued specs still in used despite their age by Ford, Toyota, etc. is that the same copyright issues tends continued usage by OEMs of these specs despite their age. For that reason, it would be a big help to the community if MS provided the XSDs for the ANSI-issued X12 specs as is done for the ASC-issued ones. For each ASC-issued spec, such as 04000, there are many documents: 830, 856, etc. This multiplies out to scores if not hundreds of handcrafted XSDs one may need to produce (as is our case) to implements broad X12 support in Logic Apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process with outlier EDI Schemas is to find the closest one and modify it to support the version you need.

What do you mean by 'unsuccessfully adapting'?  This is not an uncommon thing.

Since the spec is so old, one thing I would very much consider is bumping the interchanges up to a 'current' :) version, even just 00204.  I'm not sure the specific value 00200 will work with BizTalk EDI.

You would use a custom Pipeline Component for the incoming and should be able to use the EDI.Override properties on outbound.

Comment: Thanks, I am using 00204. It is properly targeted in a Logic Apps Decode X12 action, w/beginning:

`...<b:schemaInfo version="1.0" document_type="830"
          standard="EDI"
          standards_version="00200"
          root_reference="X12_00200_830"
          displayroot_reference="X12_00200_830"
          xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003"
          X12ConditionDesignator_Check="No" />
    </xs:appinfo>
...`

By 'unsuccessfully adapting' I meant I was not done.